# PowerApps Lookup function producing error

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

I have two SharePoint lists Desks and Desk Reservations. I want to get the building name in column Building in Desks where the `ReservedDeskID` from Desk Reservations equals `DeskID` in Desks. I am using this formula:

```
LookUp(Desks, DeskID = ThisItem.ReservedDeskID,Building)
```

But I get an error "Expected Text Value" all the fields are single line of text except Building which is Choice in the SharePoint list with all choices being text.

Comment: Where are you adding this formula? On label/input control inside Gallery control where the gallery items are pointing to "Desk Reservations" data source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
LookUp(Desks, DeskID = ThisItem.ReservedDeskID, Building.Value)
```